# CamelCaseNamingStrategy not respected for complex type, [FromBody] not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model, json.net

Setting up the context first, using an example similar to my actual code. My model is as follows:

```
public sealed class MyModel
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public MyIdentities Id {get; set;}
}
```

The api is as follows:

```
[ODataRoute(SomeRoute)]
public async Task<IActionResult> PatchAsync([FromBody] MyModel mod)
{
   // Some Code
}
```

In startup.cs I have CamelCaseNamingStrategy defined as follows:

```
 services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
     var contractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
     {
          NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy(),
      };

      options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = contractResolver;
      options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
});
```

Now when I'm trying to hit the api from postman, using the below request body- the object "mod" is coming as null, even though ModelState is valid.

```
{
   "Id":{}
}
```

The object "mod" is NOT null with the below request body:

```
{
   "id":{}
}
```

Basically [FromBody] is not parsing the body in the first case. Could someone please explain me why?

Comment: I tried as you mentioned,but it worked well,did you missed other settings related ?

Answer (score -1):

I am using

```
  options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
        new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
```

Comment: Isn't that same as the one I have?